# Virtual void not being overridden with override keyword in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

I am trying to make a class the user of my library can derive from and  then access a method for debugging the times of each action. Because my main debug method, where most information is stored, is static (and needs to be), I cannot use it to derive a class or add an overridable method in it. To combat this, I added the following code:

```
public static class Debug
{
    internal static void CallObjectEvent(string log)
    {
        new Call().CallEvent(new Log(log, Timer.GetTime()));
    }
}

internal class Call : IDebug
{
    internal void CallEvent(Log log)
    {
        base.Event(log);
    }
}

public class IDebug
{
    public virtual void Event(Log log) {Console.WriteLine("test");}
}

class Program : IDebug
{
    public override void Event(Log log)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(log.log);
    }
}
```

Every time, it outputs 'test' instead of the log message. How can I fix this? Are there any alternatives to do the same thing?

Comment: The fact you have used I for a class prefix, made this huge confusing to understand. Use standard naming conventions

Comment: ? That doesn't have anything to do with the problem, and I initially wanted it to be an interface (hence the I), but remembered I cant call on members, so I made it a class.

Comment: Also this is not a [mcve]

Comment: `base.Event(...)` will always call `IDebug.Event` even if that method has been overridden. You probably meant `Event(...)`

Comment: How would I make it a minimal reproductive example? The second I take out the static method for context, you have people complaining about just having one class. Also, I don't know if this is genuinely a language design bug, or me messing up somewhere along the chain of classes, so the extra code is necessary.

Comment: When i can paste it into .net fiddle or my ide and it just works.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Calling Event() instead of base.Event() returns the same results.

Comment: Where do you instantiate an object of class `Program`?

Comment: Program is the default class from the console template with Main()

Comment: The other problem is that you are *always* constructing a `new Call`, not a new generic type.

Comment: @TheGeneral I disagree, this directly shows the problem he's having and, apart from some formatting choices, is quite minimal.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412956).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Debug.CallObjectEvent()` method explicitly instantiates a `Call` object and calls the overridden method in that class:

```
public static class Debug
{
    internal static void CallObjectEvent(string log)
    {
        new Call().CallEvent(new Log(log, Timer.GetTime()));
    }
}
```

The `CallEvent()` method in the `Call` class simply calls `base.Event()`, which resolves to `IDebug.Event()`. The `Program.Event()` override is never invoked because `Program` is not in the class hierarchy at the point of the call.

When you override a method or property, the override applies only to the class where it is defined (and all of its child classes, of course). Since `Program` isn't a parent class of `Call` there's no reason why its overrides would ever be referenced.

From what you've written it looks like you're trying to set up a system for handling different log outputs depending on the program's requirements. You need a way to register the appropriate log writer for your program. Something like:

```cs
public interface ILogWriter
{
    void Event(Log item);
}

private class DefaultLogWriter : ILogWriter
{
    public void Event(Log item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[test] {item.Time} {item.Message}");
    }
}

internal static class Debug
{
    private static ILogWriter _writer = null;

    public static ILogWriter Writer 
    { 
        get
        {
            if (_writer == null)
                _writer = new DefaultLogWriter();
            return _writer;
        }
        set => _writer = value;
    }

    internal static void CallObjectEvent(string log)
    {
        Writer.Event(new Log(log, Timer.GetTime()));
    }
}

class Program
{
    private class MyLogWriter : ILogWriter
    {
        public void Event(Log item)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"[MyLogWriter] {item.Time} {item.Message}");
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Debug.Writer = new MyLogWriter();

        Debug.CallObjectEvent("Test message.");
    }       
}
```